# Mercural: Delete parent change-sets, continue from older change-set?

Tags: mercurial

I've got a problem with a repository where I tried to clean up a 5 head default branch, merging them one by one, but several things went wrong inside and outside of mercurial and it all just went hideously wrong.

I got everything into one head, in the default branch, and updated into it, but the system was very badly broken...

I've updated to a previous revision that works fine, and I'd like to forget everything that exists ahead of it. I can't just use hg revert --all --rev xxx as that'd mean when I commit next, it'll create a new head, and I'll be in the same situation again, where I can never merge theses two heads as the 2nd head will update and delete files trashing the system.

What can I do?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review your changes by:

```
hg glog
```

or:

```
hg serv --port 8888
```

then strip unwanted changesets by:

```
hg strip REV
```

Comment: Ah, this seems to be via extensions. I've not explored these, I'll enable them and give it a try. I'll be back. :)

Comment: That worked wonderfully. I've always been taught never to try to go back in time with source control, never to "amend current change sets", etc, just to commit again. In this instance though I really couldn't find any other way. 

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting some odd behaviour now. I've striped all revisions ahead of my "good" revision. My "good" revision is tagged as tip, but if I run hg update tip, it then updates to the previous latest, as if I did't do the stripping in the first place. Also, then I can't update back to the previous revision number, as that doesn't update any files to bring me good again. I have to update to the previous revision number. Any idea?

Comment: Any striped changes saved into `.hg` directory and you can `hg unbandle` them. http://selenic.com/hg/help/unbundle